# How to improve this example?

Tags: awk

```
$ seq 12 | awk '{ if(NR%2) { print $0, (NR+1)/2 } else { print $0, NR/2} }'
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 3
6 3
7 4
8 4
9 5
10 5
11 6
12 6
```

How do I change the above command? I want to print:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 2
6 2
7 3
8 3
9 3
10 4
11 4
12 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. Just applying your algorithm to 3:

```
seq 12|awk '{if((NR%3)==1) { print $0, (NR+2)/3 } else if ((NR%3)==2) { print $0, (NR+1)/3 } else { print $0, NR/3} }'
```

But I'm sure there is also a shorter algo...

Comment: Shorter is for example: seq 12|awk '{print $0, ((NR-1)+3-(NR-1)%3)/3}'

Comment: Or, generalized: seq 12|awk 'BEGIN {s=3};{print $0, ((NR-1)+s-(NR-1)%s)/s}' change s to any steprange you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $0, int((NR+2)/3)}'
```